# How to specify the string representation for a class

Tags: python

Suppose I have:

```
class A:

  @classmethod
  def __str__(cls): return 'A'
```

The intent is for `str(A)` to return `'A'`.

But instead I get `<class '__main__.A'>`.

The same thing happens when I define `__repr__`.

How can I define a string representation for a class?

I need something that will respond to `str(A)` since I don't have control over the call.

Comment: `__str__` and `__repr__` are looked up on the type of the object in question. If the object in question is a class, then its type is its metaclass.

Comment: So what should I do to get the result I want?

Comment: You need to write a custom metaclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a metaclass that overrides the `__str__` method of the base class of a class object, `type`:

```
class meta(type):
    def __str__(cls):
        return cls.__name__

class A(metaclass=meta):
    pass

print(str(A))
```

This outputs:

```
A
```